# How do you get the curvature tensor of the Schwarzschild Solution?

Tags: physics, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, curvature

So, on the Wikipedia page on the derivation of the Schwärzschild solution , I get everything up to the part about the Ricci tensor.

[image]

What were the components of the tensor that were used?

Could someone *please* just show me a step-by-step mathematical description of the solution of the tensor?

If the photo isn't clear enough, here's the link to the page.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_Schwarzschild_solution#Using_the_field_equations_to_find_A.28r.29_and_B.28r.29
😄

Comment: $\tiny \mbox{I wonder if I can read those indices: } \Gamma_{ikl}^{jmn}$

Comment: Here It is. The link, I didn't know if another photo would be any better.